# rails jquery plug in select2 remove tag confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to take advantage of the tags adding and removing with select2. Since we thought that removing a tag was too easy by clicking delete or the x and we want to have a remove confirmation before actually removing the tag. I was wondering if i can get some direction of how to implement since it was not in any documentation in select2. Maybe have a document on click to detect if the x is being click and backspace is being enter for the field. and prompt a user confirmation ?

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html

Comment: Nope.. i don't think that is possible

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends ,
            we can manually block the close event ..
Here i have tried sample.. this is sameple. You can continue using this method.

select2-search-choice-close - > This is the class for close event . we can add the event and workout anything. in this sample just i added hi alert.

```
$(".select2-search-choice-close").click(function (e) { alert('hi'); });
```